# Теги в IntelliJ Idea в JSF/Facelets оборачиваются в CDATA

Tags: java, jsf

Любые теги, например: p, a; после ввода в редактор и нажатия Tab оборачиваются в

```
<![CDATA[
<a></a>
]]>
```

Так происходит, если создавать файл как JSF/Facelets, если создавать как HTML, то теги создаются нормально.

В чём может быть проблема?